# Using a var as a partial name?

Tags: handlebars.js

Im trying to render partials based upon a variable name, according to [these docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html) the correct method is:

> Subexpressions do not resolve variables so whichPartial must be a
>   function. If a simple variable has the partial name, it's possible to
>   resolve it via the lookup helper.

```
{{> (lookup . 'myVariable') }}
```

So I have tried:

```
{{#each index.types}}
    {{> (lookup . this.type) }}
{{/each}}
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: The partial undefined could not be found
```

I've also output the following in the loop:

```
{{this.type}}
```

The correct partial string is being read.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with using {{this}} as partial name. I managed to solve it by using partial block as follows:

```
{{#each this as |tab| }}
      {{> (tab)}}
{{/each}}
```

In your case you could try:

```
{{#each index.types as |item| }}
  {{> (item.type)}}
{{/each}}
```